# Calculating And Updating Weighted Moving Average Forecast Data Using ADO Recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access 2016, I am trying to calculate weighted moving average forecasts and update my forecast table with the results.

My code loops through the recordset without any issues but my current logic will not calculate the weighted averages. As it is, it is just returning the actual sales for each period. I have been debugging this for sometime and cannot wrap my head around it.

I am using an ADO class for CRUD operations with SQL server as my backend via ODBC. In my code below, I have removed error handling to compress my code. As follows:

```
Sub WMAForecast( _
                    lngCompanyID As Long, _
                    lngItemID As Long, _
                    dtmStartDate As Date, _
                    dtmEndDate As Date, _
                    intPeriods As Integer)                    

    ' Object related declarations ->
    Dim objRs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim objDb1 As clADO
    Dim objDb2 As clADO
    Dim objEh As clError
    Dim strSQL1 As String: strSQL1 = vbNullString
    Dim strSQL2 As String: strSQL2 = vbNullString

    '// Generics variables ->
    Dim lngRecords As Long: lngRecords = 0
    Dim lngDetailsCount: lngDetailsCount = 0
    Dim lngDetailRecords: lngDetailRecords = 0
    Dim dblReturn As Double: dblReturn = 0
    Dim dblTempSum As Double: dblTempSum = 0
    Dim dblWeightSum As Double: dblWeightSum = 0

    '// Loop counters ->
    Dim i As Long: i = 0
    Dim j As Long: j = 0
    Dim k As Long: k = 0

    '// Calculate the sum of weights ->
    dblWeightSum = intPeriods * (intPeriods + 1) / 2

    '// Declare an array to store the weights ->
    Dim arrWeights As Variant
    ReDim arrWeights(1 To intPeriods)

    '// Construct SQL ->
    strSQL1 = "SELECT Sum(ItemDemandHistory.DemandUnits) AS Issues, PlanningCalendar.WeekEndDate, ItemDemandHistory.ItemID " & _
    "FROM PlanningCalendar INNER JOIN ItemDemandHistory ON PlanningCalendar.WeekEndDate = ItemDemandHistory.WeekEndDate " & _
    "GROUP BY PlanningCalendar.WeekEndDate, ItemDemandHistory.ItemID, PlanningCalendar.CompanyID " & _
    "HAVING PlanningCalendar.WeekEndDate>=? " & _
    "AND PlanningCalendar.WeekEndDate<=? " & _
    "AND ItemDemandHistory.ItemID=? " & _
    "AND PlanningCalendar.CompanyID=?"

    '// Validate parameters ->
    If Not fIsNullOrEmpty(strSQL1) And _
        Not fIsNullOrEmpty(lngCompanyID) And _
        Not fIsNullOrEmpty(lngItemID) And _
        Not fIsNullOrEmpty(dtmStartDate) And _
        Not fIsNullOrEmpty(dtmStartDate) And _
        Not fIsNullOrEmpty(intPeriods) Then

        '// Initialize database ->
        Set objDb1 = New clADO
        With objDb1
            .Initialize DatabaseType:=DBTypeEnum.TypeODBC
            .CursorLocation = adUseClient: .CommandType = adCmdText: .CursorType = adOpenStatic

            '// Retrieve recordset ->
            Set objRs = .ExecuteQuery(strSQL1, dtmStartDate, dtmEndDate, lngItemID, lngCompanyID)
            With objRs
                If Not (.EOF And .BOF) Then
                    If .RecordCount > 0 Then

                        '// Collect the number of records ->
                        lngRecords = .RecordCount

                        '// Construct and array to store the cummulative values ->
                        Dim arrCumulative As Variant
                        ReDim arrCumulative(1 To lngRecords) As Double

                        '// Construct and array to store the cummulative values ->
                        Dim arrWMA As Variant
                        ReDim arrWMA(1 To lngRecords) As Double

                        '// Move cursor to first position ->
                        .MoveFirst

                        '// Traverse through the recordset ->
                        For i = 1 To lngRecords

                            '// Set counter defaults ->
                            dblTempSum = 0
                            k = 0

                            '// Check if first record and assign first value to cummulative array ->
                            If i = 1 Then
                                arrCumulative(i) = .Fields(0)
                            Else
                                arrCumulative(i) = .Fields(0) + arrCumulative(i - 1)
                            End If

                            '// At points <= period N, calculate a simple average ->
                            '// Example using 3 Periods: If N=3, MA(1) = first series point, MA(2) = Average(first two points), MA(3) = Average(first three points)...etc ->
                            If i <= intPeriods Then
                                arrWMA(i) = arrCumulative(i) / i
                            Else
                                '// When i > intPeriods, the moving average calculation kicks in ->
                                For j = i - intPeriods + 1 To i
                                    k = k + 1
                                    dblTempSum = dblTempSum + .Fields(0) * k
                                Next j
                                arrWMA(i) = dblTempSum / dblWeightSum

                                '// Initialize database ->
                                Set objDb2 = New clADO
                                With objDb2
                                    .Initialize DatabaseType:=DBTypeEnum.TypeODBC: .CommandType = adCmdText

                                    '// Construct SQL ->
                                    strSQL2 = "UPDATE ItemDemandForecast " & _
                                    "SET ForecastUnits=? " & _
                                    "WHERE CompanyID=? " & _
                                    "AND ItemID=? " & _
                                    "AND WeekEndDate=?"

                                    '// Execute SQL ->
                                    lngDetailRecords = .ExecuteNonQuery(strSQL2, CDbl(arrWMA(i)), lngCompanyID, lngItemID, objRs.Fields(1))

                                    '// Increment record count ->
                                    lngDetailsCount = lngDetailsCount + lngDetailRecords
                                End With
                            End If
                        .MoveNext
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        End With
    End If

    '// Cleanup ->
    Erase arrCumulative
    Erase arrWMA
    Erase arrWeights
    If Not objRs Is Nothing Then Set objRs = Nothing
    If Not objDb1 Is Nothing Then Set objDb1 = Nothing
    If Not objDb2 Is Nothing Then Set objDb2 = Nothing
    If Not objEh Is Nothing Then Set objEh = Nothing

End Function
```

Below is my data with expected outputs:

```
CompanyID   ItemID  Planning_Period Period_Ending   Demand_Units    Forecast_Units
1           10      1               2016-01-10      814             814
1           10      2               2016-01-17      1386            1386
1           10      3               2016-01-24      571             1100
1           10      4               2016-01-31      827             883.17
1           10      5               2016-02-07      1217            834.83
1           10      6               2016-02-14      1143            979.33
1           10      7               2016-02-21      1249            1115.00
1           10      8               2016-02-28      1303            1208.33
1           10      9               2016-03-06      1283            1258.33
1           10      10              2016-03-13      1379            1284.00
1           10      11              2016-03-20      990             1334.33
1           10      12              2016-03-27      1241            1168.50
```

To summarize my objectives:

1. Calculate a weighted moving average forecast for an item / period based on previous sales history.
2. Using the calculated forecast, update the forecast for each matching item / period.

Comment: Should post source data as text formatted as table so readers can easily copy data. That dataset does not have data needed to run the function (CompanyID, ItemID, StartDate).

Comment: "I cannot get it to actually calculate the weighted averages as expected" - what does it do *instead* of what you expect?

Comment: Why do you have VBA and VB.net tags? Should be one or the other.

Comment: @tamosa   It is apparent from the code comments, parameter validation code, error checking (which you say is removed) and other clean-up code, that you are thorough and follow good coding practices.  For the record, I was very direct in my comments not to be rude, rather it's apparent that you know how to code well, so I am just surprised that your question has no mention of any debugging steps taken.

Comment: @CPerkins - Thanks for the sledgehammer feedback! I have been debugging this for hours and just cannot wrap my head around it. Perhaps its my logic, I am not the best programmer when it comes to loop structures and ordinals, still learning, but that's why I am here, asking for help!

Comment: @tamosa  Sledgehammers are useful tools... but I hope it didn't hurt, that wasn't my intention! :)  I've just experienced a variety of requests on SO (and elsewhere) and many times the asker has not always attempt to understand it as you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is that the code is not calculating a moving average because the summation code does not refer back to values from previous rows.

---

First review this code:

```
dblWeightSum = intPeriods * (intPeriods + 1) / 2
```

That is simply the sum of integers from 1 up to intPeriods, like `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + intPeriods`.

Now go to the code

```
dblTempSum = 0
k = 0
...

For j = i - intPeriods + 1 To i
    k = k + 1
    dblTempSum = dblTempSum + .Fields(0) * k
Next j
arrWMA(i) = dblTempSum / dblWeightSum
```

**First notice that there are no previous values added to the sum.**  In other words, it is not including previous value at all.  There are no references to previous values.  Therefore, this cannot be a running average of multiple rows.

Next, consider that the **total number** of loop iterations is simply intPeriods.  `k` effectively starts at 1 then counts up from 1 to intPeriods.  Each iterations of the loop multiplies the **same current value** `.Fields(0)` by the current k value.  Overall, the loop produces a sum rewritten as the following

```
dblTempSum = .Fields(0) * (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + intPeriods)
```

Does that look familiar?  It should, since it contains the same sum as stored in `dblWeightSum` as explained earlier.

Therefore, the final line of code from the snippet above ends up reducing like the following...

```
arrWMA(i) == dblTempSum / dblWeightSum
          == .Fields(0) * (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + intPeriods) / (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + intPeriods)
          == .Fields(0)
```

The value of `arrWMA(i)` is what updates the field `ForecastUnits` in the subsequent code.  Thus, the field intended for the moving average instead ends up with the original, single value from the same row... just as you have observed.

---

Sorry, but I'm not able to post correct weighted moving average code right now.  However, the key is to replace the current loop from the snippet above with a sum of current weighted value minus the previous weighted sum.  To do this properly, I think that you need at least one more array for storing the weighted sum AND you need to subtract values from the existing sum which are beyond the moving period size (intPeriod).  Review a trusted algorithm for precise steps.

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is a second set of eyes to solve ones coding problems! Thanks for the help C Perkins :)